# Newbie - Rails View Calculation - onchange?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am quite new to Ruby on Rails and what to make sure I set of on the right foot.  I want to do some simple "Live Calculations" and am not sure of the best method.
If we use the cookbook example.

Each Recipe has many ingredients.
Each ingredient has a description, qty, cost and a total.

What I want to do is the following;
1) ingredient.total = ingredient.qty x ingredient.cost
2) recipe.grand_total = ingredients.sum(total)

Each time the user changes the values in ingredient.qty or ingredient.cost I want to update the totals.

What i don't know is how or where to do this :(

Any help would be great :)

Thanks in Advance,
Neil

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to do this using javascript by using either onChange or perhaps observe_field on the two fields mentioned above.

When one of them is updated then the javascript will call your bit of code that will carry out the calculation.

Comment: hey,
thanks for the info.  I thought so too but I can only find examples to actually post the form when it is updated.  I want the calculation to stay on the client side (or at least not update the DB) until the user saves the form.  Thus giving them a chance to cancel.  Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks again, Neil

Answer (score 0):

Have been messing around and so far have come up with this explanation pulled together from various places so thought I would share.

```
<tr class="recipe_item">
  <td><%= f.text_field :ingredient %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :quantity, :class => "quantity", :onblur => "this.up('.recipe_item').down('.total').value = (parseInt(this.value) * parseInt(this.up('.recipe_item').down('.cost').value)) ;" %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :cost, :class => "cost", :onblur => "this.up('.recipe_item').down('.total').value =  parseInt(this.up('.recipe_item').down('.quantity').value) * (parseInt(this.value)) ;" %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :total, :class => "total", :readonly => true %></td>
</tr>
```

Not sure how efficient this is but it seems to work for the first step at least. Next thing is to find a way to summ all the recipe items to a grand total.  Anyone got any comments or ideas?
Thanks
Neil